# Control the screen resolution of an external projector with a long cable

Tags: 12.10, video, projector

I'm using a Lenovo W530 with (soon to be upgraded) 12.10. Whenever I plug-in an external **moitor** screen resolution discovery is accurate and I can use dual screen mode happily.

However the situation is different when plug-in a external projector. Using a modern projector with the supplied display cable, detection works well, however with older projectors or when there is a (long) cable extension between laptop and projector (as it is common in conference rooms and hotels), resolution discovery fails and the only option is 640x480.

This [bug has been reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-control-center-unity/+bug/1286955).

How can I improve the resolution discovery (or change the resolution manually)?

Answer (score 1):

The Lenovo W530 (and probably a series of other laptops) have both a VGA and a (Mini)DisplayPort video exit. When using the Mini DisplayPort with a VGA adapter, the discovery of the projector's resolution works (mostly) reliably.

While this is another cable to carry around, it solves the embarrassment of not being able to project.